# set a dependency property in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom UserControl which exposes the following dependency property: CanEdit. The property was created using a snippet and the generated code is:

```
#region CanEdit

/// <summary>
/// CanEdit Dependency Property
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty CanEditProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CanEdit", typeof(bool), typeof(RequisitionItem),
        new PropertyMetadata((bool)false));

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the CanEdit property. This dependency property 
/// indicates ....
/// </summary>
public bool CanEdit {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(CanEditProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CanEditProperty, value); }
}

#endregion
```

I'm trying to set this property to True on the parent UserControl, like this:

```
<RequisitionItem CanEdit="True" />
```

but the property stays False.
Why is that?

Comment: Your code as displayed will work. Something external to what you have posted is most likely causing the issue.

Comment: You're right, I was setting this property to false on another dependency property changed callback that was called first. My bad =$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the child items have the property still set to false this sounds like an inheritance issue.

See this [page on value inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx), there is one section called [Making a Custom Property Inheritable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx#Making_a_Custom_Property_Inheritable), which might offer some help.